# Why gradient layer in UITableViewCell not cover entire frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, cagradientlayer

I try to make a standard gradient top-bottom with long UIView. But it's not full. The nib is part of UITableViewCell, so I don't have access to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44737260/1137814).

[image]

I've tried to call `contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` from the code version of this view. I called it when UITableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called. But it's no effect.

I prepare the gradient in `awakeFromNib()`.

```
let colors = [
            UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 33/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 51/255.0, blue: 51/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor]
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds
gradient.colors = colors
gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: i kind of had the same issue please look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974152/uitableviewcell-background-gradient-not-working-at-first-render

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use view's `bounds`instead of `frame`, because your layer is inside of the view, and the frame may have an offset.

The layout of the view is changed after `awakeFromNib`. So you should resize the layer in `layoutSubviews` of the view. For this create a property `gradient` and:

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    ...
    let colors = [
                UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 33/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 51/255.0, blue: 51/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor]
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = colors
    gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0) 
    ...
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradient.frame = bounds
}
```

**EDIT**: An alternative is a custom view with own layer class:

```
public class GradientLayer: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 33/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    @IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 51/255.0, blue: 51/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let colors = [ startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor ]
        if let gradient = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer {
            gradient.colors = colors
        }
    }
}
```

This is more elegant, because you can replace the static colors with *IB inspectables*, and you have a reusable component view.

Comment: Good one hence +1

Comment: Sorry typo in my question. It's actually use `bounds` from the gradient view. I'll give your solution a try anyway.

Comment: I just saw that the layer belongs to another view. I've changed the code, but I think it would be better if the view containing the layer (`gradientView`) would manage the layout of the layer.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik: You could be right, but this is from the OP's code. I won't change that, and this code compiles without errors.

Comment: @clemens - ok ,but we can suggest

Comment: @Anbu.karthik: Yeah, I think using constants or even color sets is generally a quite good idea.

Comment: @clemens I accept your answer. And thank you for mentioning _IB inspectables_.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik do you mean creating constant for all the RGB values?

Comment: @SetoElkahfi - yes, see this for e.g `33/255.0` its common , just create the constant for reusablity.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let gradient = baseView.layer.sublayers?[0] as? CAGradientLayer {
            gradient.frame = self.bounds
        }
 }
```