# UITableViewCell background gradient not working at first render

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view. I create my cells using xib files.
I need 1 cell(which is the current user) to be a gradient background, I created a background gradient layer but it does not fit to view. After I pull list down, it works. [image: Broken one]

[image: Working one]

You can see screenshots i have and this is my code

```
//In the table cell,
if data.userUniqueId != nil && userUIID != nil && data.userUniqueId! == userUIID! {
            let startColor = UIColor(red: 253/255.0, green: 162/255.0, blue: 75/255.0, alpha: 1)
            let endColor = UIColor(red:251/255.0, green:215/255.0, blue: 126/255.0, alpha:1)
            self.setGradient(colors: [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor],angle: 90)
            self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = 2
            number.textColor = UIColor.white

        }
```

And this is gradient method

```
 func setGradient(colors: [CGColor], angle: Float = 0) {
        let gradientLayerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height))
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = gradientLayerView.bounds
        gradient.colors = colors

        let alpha: Float = angle / 360
        let startPointX = powf(
            sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.75) / 2)),
            2
        )
        let startPointY = powf(
            sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0) / 2)),
            2
        )
        let endPointX = powf(
            sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.25) / 2)),
            2
        )
        let endPointY = powf(
            sinf(2 * Float.pi * ((alpha + 0.5) / 2)),
            2
        )

        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(endPointX),y: CGFloat(endPointY))
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(startPointX), y: CGFloat(startPointY))

        gradientLayerView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayerView.layer, at: 0)
    }
```

And also how can I remove gradient from layer for next usage of cells?

**EDIT:**
Table View Codes

```
extension RecordsViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ScoreBoardCell", for: indexPath) as? ScoreBoardCell {
            let score = self.values[indexPath.row]
            cell.setData(indexPath.row, score)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
gradient.frame = gradientLayerView.bounds
```

At the time this code runs in `cellForRowAt`, your `gradientLayerView` has not yet been fully laid out, so its `bounds` are not yet known. Thus, you are saddling your `gradient` with a `frame` which will not fit its view after layout does take place.

I *think* you can solve the problem by moving the call to `cell.setData` to `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`, at which point the cell size should be known.

> And also how can I remove gradient from layer for next usage of cells?

Well, the problem here is that your condition has no alternative:

```
if data.userUniqueId != nil && userUIID != nil && data.userUniqueId! == userUIID!
```

The question is: what if *not*? In that case, if the gradient layer has been added, it needs to be removed. You have provided no logic for that situation. — Also you need to be careful because what if the gradient layer has been added and your logic now causes you to add *another* gradient layer? Basically your whole approach fails to take account of the most fundamental fact about table view cells, namely that they are reused.

Comment: Does overriding layoutSubView into UITableCellView work?

Comment: It might, yes. Give it a try.

Comment: It worked thanks, I have an else statement but I didn't write it here. I could not find how to delete gradient from CALayer

Comment: You do not "delete gradient from CALayer". You remove the gradient layer itself. That is what `removeFromSuperlayer` is for, yes?

Answer (score 1):

[Xcode 12 Swift 5.2]

After looking for hours nothing worked for me. Changing gradient layer's bounds in `layoutSubviews()` or setting a gradient layer in `willDisplayCell()`.

so I have created a gradient layer and created an `UIImage` of it and added that image as background. and that worked like charm here is a sweet and simple extension to **convert the Gradient layer into UIImage**.

```
func getImageFrom(gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer) -> UIImage? {
        var gradientImage:UIImage?
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.frame.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            gradientLayer.render(in: context)
            gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return gradientImage
    }
```

Code for making a `CAGradientLayer` :

```
 let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.init().Hex(hexString: "#EB0089").cgColor,
            UIColor.init().Hex(hexString: "#FD2E59").cgColor
        ]
        
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
        
       
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.frame = Button1.bounds

let GradientImage = UIImage().getImageFrom(gradientLayer: gradientLayer)
```

set `GradientImage` wherever you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this inside

```
var once  = true

override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  if once  {
        let startColor = UIColor(red: 253/255.0, green: 162/255.0, blue: 75/255.0, alpha: 1)
        let endColor = UIColor(red:251/255.0, green:215/255.0, blue: 126/255.0, alpha:1)
        self.setGradient(colors: [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor],angle: 90)
        once = false 
   }   
}
```

Where the cell bounds are correctly rendered , When you want to remove

```
cell.contentView.subviews { 
  if $0.tag == 200 {
    $0.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

And give it a tag

```
 let gradientLayerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height))
 gradientLayerView.tag = 200
```

When you add anything to cell don't froget tp add it to `contentView`

```
contentView.addSubview(gradientLayerView)
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Gradient Effect on TableView Cell]

```
private func applyGradientEffect() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // create new gradient layer
            // remove already added layer
            // set gradient frame
            // set gradient start and end colors
            // set gradient start and end points
            // set gradient locations
            // Important always use insertSublayer: yourView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```